# Bootstrap button in nav horizontal menu causes text misalignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some code that was substantially produced by `ASP.NET` Core scaffolding. I'm a CSS novice. The problem is that in this menu there is a button that causes the option to its left to be slightly higher than the other options. The button is Logout and the option to its left is Profile. Through trial and error I have narrowed the cause to the `btn` class on Logout.

Why is this happening and what is the fix?

Here's a web page that replicates the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Tracker1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="logout" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's default `1PX` [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) CSS for the `btn` class on Bootstrap-4 which causes the issue as it is not applied on the 'Profile' `#manage` element.

> *Why does the border have the effect?*
>
> > In CSS, elements have their own border property. The border will be invisible if its style is not defined. This is because the style defaults to `none`. In our case, border is defined with `1px` which consume space around the element. If border to set like `border: 0` *or* `border: none`, this will not consume any space.

> *Why isn't Home affected? It doesn't have the btn style.*
>
> > 'Home' are wrapped under container `<ul>` which having bootstrap `flex-grow-1` class and this `flex-grow-1` class applied [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) css to the element.
> >
> > > *And how does CSS [`flex-grow'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) work?* 
> > > Flex-grow tells our element whether or not it can take up additional space. When we set a flex-grow value of 1 or larger, we are telling our element to grow to take up the available space. An element with a flex-grow value set to 0 will not grow to take up available space.

[This `flex-grow` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) also helps you.

[image: View on Codepen]

Snippet:

```css
#manage {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Tracker1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="logout" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

---

> Here, short code snippet where `3rd` and `4th` menu doesn't have `btn` class but `4th` menu have `flex-grow` css to their parent container which lead `4th` menu to occupy space and looks similar to the `2nd` menu :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="logout" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Menu with border (btn)</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Menu with <i>flex-grow</i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

---

> Now here, `3rd` and `4th` menus doesn't have `btn` class and also `4th` menu doesn't have `flex-grow-1` bootstrap css class to their parent `<ul>` element. In this case, `4th` menu doesn't occupy additional space and looks similar to the `1st` and `3rd` menu irrespective of wrapping into another `<ul></ul>` element :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Normal Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="logout" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Menu with "btn"</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Normal menu</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Normal menu</i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I accept your fix works @cursorrux, but your explanation is a little brief for me. Why does the border have the effect, and why isn't Home affected? It doesn't have the btn style.

Comment: @Ian added short brief with document citation.

Answer (score 0):

**Home** is not affected because it is in another unordered HTML list, if you remove
`</ul><ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">` between the second and third `nav-item` then you will see **Home** not aligned with **Logout** as you can see in the following snippet:

```css
#manage {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Tracker1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="logout" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                        
                   <!-- remove this </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1"> -->
                    
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

To solve the issue you need all the `nav-item` elements to be in the same unordered HTML list and then if the classes have borders like in this case where the `btn` class has, you should make all the `nav-item` elements have the same classes. As @cursorrux said `Logout`has a transparent border and all the others don't.

**Review the following code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Tracker1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="manage" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="logout" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```